# Mesclar duas séries (zoo) de uma mesma variável fazendo a interseção e filling

Tags: r

Tenho duas séries zoo assim:

a:

```
data        valor
01-02-2010   2
01-03-2010   0
01-04-2010   9
```

b:

```
data        valor
01-06-2010   3
01-07-2010   6
01-08-2010   2
```

Desejo um conjunto c desta forma:

c:

```
data        valor
01-02-2010   2
01-03-2010   0
01-04-2010   9
01-05-2010   NA
01-06-2010   3
01-07-2010   6
01-08-2010   2
```

Como prosseguir?

Comment: Só para esclarecer: a coluna `valor` do data frame `c` tem estes valores da questão `(2, 2, 2, NA, 3, 6, 2)` ou deveriam ser os valores originais de `a` e `b`, intercalados por um `NA`?

Comment: exato consertei a pergunta

Comment: Um `dput()` ajudaria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia foi basicamente criar uma adaptação da função `rbind.zoo()`. Ela verifica quais índices contíguos não estão presentes em `a` ou `b`, cria um novo objeto `zoo` apenas com estes índices e valores `NA` e une o novo `zoo` aos originais, preenchendo-os.

```
library(zoo)

# Criar exemplo reprodutível
seq_mes <- function(inicio, tamanho) {
  seq(from = as.Date(inicio), by = '1 month', length.out = tamanho)
}

a <- zoo(c(2, 9, 0), seq_mes('2010-02-01', 3))
b <- zoo(c(3, 6, 2), seq_mes('2010-06-01', 3))

# Definir e aplicar função
rbind_preenche <- function(..., periodo) {
  unido <- rbind(...)
  periodo_total <- seq(from = min(index(unido)),
                       to = max(index(unido)), by = periodo)

  a_criar <- periodo_total[! periodo_total %in% index(unido)]
  novo <- zoo(rep(NA, length(a_criar)), a_criar)
  rbind(unido, novo)
}

rbind_preenche(a, b, periodo = '1 month')
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com uma pequena gambiarra. Imagino que deva existir alguma maneira mais simples, mas esta abaixo está funcionando como deveria para pelo menos este exemplo.

Em primeiro lugar, eu criei os data frames `a` e `b`, como no exemplo da pergunta:

```
a <- data.frame(data=seq(from=as.Date("01-02-2010", format="%m-%d-%Y"), 
  to=as.Date("01-04-2010", format="%m-%d-%Y"), "days"), valor=c(2, 0, 9))

b <- data.frame(data=seq(from=as.Date("01-06-2010", format="%m-%d-%Y"), 
  to=as.Date("01-08-2010", format="%m-%d-%Y"), "days"), valor=c(3, 6, 2))
```

A seguir, criei todas as datas que deveriam aparecer no data frame final, chamado `c`. Chamei estas datas de `data_final`. Criei uma sequência diária, começando no mínimo das datas e terminando no máximo delas:

```
data_final <- seq(from=min(a$data, b$data), to=max(a$data, b$data), "days")
```

Depois foi só criar o data frame `c`. A primeira versão dele possui as datas armazenadas dentro de `data_final` e apenas `NA` na coluna valor:

```
c <- data.frame(data=data_final, valor=NA)
```

Isto feio, foi só atualizar as posições da coluna `valor` que possuem datas equivalentes em `a` e `b`:

```
c$valor[data_final %in% a$data] <- a$valor[a$data %in% data_final]
c$valor[data_final %in% b$data] <- b$valor[b$data %in% data_final]
c
        data valor
1 2010-01-02     2
2 2010-01-03     0
3 2010-01-04     9
4 2010-01-05    NA
5 2010-01-06     3
6 2010-01-07     6
7 2010-01-08     2
```

Comment: meus objetos são do tipo [ZOO](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf), essa abordagem não funciona, apenas com um data.frame, com um data frame utilizando a função union facilmente faz-se isso. Agradeço pela ajuda.